# How do I get this piece of code to loop until the correct input is used

Tags: c#

Cant get this to end loop. Im very new to this and only learning.

```
while (Gender != "male" || Gender != "Male" || Gender != "female" || Gender != "Female")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input please select type Male or Female");
    Gender = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Typo?  You meant to use `&&` instead of `||`?  Because any value will *always* be *not* one of those values.

Comment: Thanks a mil that was a very quick reply. Currently studying software development and constantly getting lost and confused with it xD

Comment: Also, aside from the fact you have missed out other gender options, you would be better off doing a case-insensitive comparison so you could also catch "MaLe" etc.

Comment: On top of the suggestions in the answers: From a user experience standpoint, I - as user - would prefer to _not_ have to type out the whole thing (where I also could make typos, etc). So, you may want to ReadKey and then check for Key M or Key F.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating an enum for your value, and use `Enum.TryParse` in a loop:

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male, Female
}
public static Gender InputGenderFromConsole()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input gender, 'male' or 'female'");
    while (true)
    {
        if (Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), ignoreCase:true, out Gender result))
        {            
            return result;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect format, please input 'male' or 'female'");
    }
}
```

Same principle would apply when parsing int, double, etc. You could also create a generic method that takes the enum type as a generic type parameter.

It is generally recommended to convert between strings and actual typed objects at the "edges" of your application, i.e. try to separate input handling from logic. Using strings when there are better types is sometimes called "stringly typed" and is considered an antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing a couple of things differently. First, create a list of valid items and then use a comparison that ignores the case. For example:

```
var validGenders = new[] { "Male", "Female" };

while (validGenders.Contains(Gender, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input please select type Male or Female");
    Gender = Console.ReadLine();        
}
```